# Unity 5: Raycast not finding blocks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Hey guys I've been working on a 2D terraria-like game, from a tutorial I found on Youtube. I've been using Quads as blocks. The link to the series is:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KONw5GX0Ixs

The only difference is I've been in a 2D project rather than a 3D. I'm trying to implement a mining system, but the clicks aren't detected much less the blocks that I'm clicking on. The system doesn't even detect the clicking, much less the blocks I'm clicking on. I'm new to coding so I'm not sure how to fix this, anything helps, thanks.

My code is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mining : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector2 direction;
    void Update() {

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Vector3 c = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);

            RaycastHit2D hit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(this.gameObject.transform.position, direction);
            Debug.Log ("hello");

            if (hit2D.collider.gameObject != null) {
                Debug.Log (hit2D.collider.gameObject);
                Destroy (hit2D.collider.gameObject);
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "hello" message isn't printed ? Are you sure this script is attached to an active object in the scene ?

Comment: @TheJavatar yeah it's attached to a gameobject in the scene

Comment: @TheJavatar I put the if statement above the if statement, I'm getting this error NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Mining.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Mining.cs:16)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change

```
Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)
```

to

```
Input.GetMouseButton(0)
```

as its

> Returns whether the given mouse button is held down.

tell me if that fix your problem. If not, I will try to figure sth out:)